# android slide menu ..when am item is clicked in slide menu the control is not going to respective page

Tags: android

code for slide menu:

```
   mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

       mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        /*getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);*/


        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    selectItem(position);

}
//}

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);

       System.out.println("&&&&&position"+position);

        switch(position){
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(home.this, ChangeActivity.class));
              //  finish();

            case 1:

                startActivity(new Intent(home.this, home.class));
                //finish();

            case 2:

                startActivity(new Intent(home.this, info_values.class));
               // finish();

            default:
                break;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you see position of clicked item in logger?

Comment: yes!!the position is printed correctly accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `break;` statement after each case block. Like following

```
  switch(position){
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(home.this, ChangeActivity.class));
          //  finish();
            break;

        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(home.this, home.class));
            //finish();
            break;

        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(home.this, info_values.class));
           // finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;


    }
```

Comment: am getting null pointer exception in my adapter class..if i include break

Comment: For that you will have to provide details of it.